# Scrape a page with AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, web-scraping

I'm using Node.js with jsDOM to scrape web pages and execute JavaScript in them. But if a page contains AJAX requests, they are not executed.

Is there an option to execute AJAX calls inside the scraped pages?

Comment: I definitely execute Javascript (using FetchExternalResources and ProcessExternalResources features of jsdom)

Comment: Try https://snapsearch.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to emulate XMLHTTPRequests. Here's an [abstraction](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/XMLHttpRequest.js). They don't work out of the box in node.js.

You will have to figure out how to get it to talk to jsdom. (Hopefully just appending a xmlhttprequest constructor to the `window` will fix it)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Actually I scrape pages with jQuery, and they seem to use "fake xhr" - jqXHR. Does your solution fix this problem too?

Comment: jqXHR is not fake xhr. its a wrapper around XMLHTTPRequest. You want a new XMLHTTPRequest object because node does not have any concept of ajax